# How do I connect to ftps server through php?

Tags: php

I want to connect to ftps server through php.
I am using **ftp_connect()**

But I am getting this warning while connection:

> Warning: ftp_connect()
>   [function.ftp-connect]:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known.

can any one help?

Answer (score 4):

PHP has a built-in function for connecting to "FTPS" servers, since secure FTP is over an SSL connection. Check out the documentation for `ftp_ssl_connect`.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php

Hope this helps!

Comment: FTP over SSL is **FTPS**. **SFTP** on the hand has nothing to do with FTP, as it is an extension of the SSH (Secure Shell) protocol. Confusing acronyms, I know.

Comment: Gah it got me again. I knew this but I got them mixed up. Thank you for the clarification. Been working with Linux too much today; I need a little more web development in my daily diet.

Answer (score -1):

This means, it is not able to  find the FTP server you are trying to connect. Either domain name doesn't exist or name resolution failed.

I guess, you are trying to connect as,

```
$server = 'ftpserver,port';
$connection = ftp_connect($server);
```

For which you can use,

```
$server = 'ftpserver'; 
$port = 'port'; 
$connection  = ftp_connect($server,$port);
```

Hope this helps.

If it does not work, Please check manual for ftp_connect again.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php